# JQuery Ajax multi array repsonse

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got the following problem. I want to display a multi array via ajax.

Javascript:

```
function getContent(HSID,HSname){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/script.gethandlungslogContent.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: { HSID : HSID },
            dataType : "json",
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById('wartungslogHead').innerHTML = HSname;
                document.getElementById('wartungslogContent').innerHTML = data.hl_aenderung;
                document.getElementById('wartungslogID').value = data.HSID;
                //document.getElementById('wartungslogID').value = data.KentID;

                document.getElementById('buttonEdit').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('buttonDelete').style.display = 'inline';
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
    include_once('../classes/class.mysql.php');

    if (isset($_POST['HSID'])){$HSID = $_POST['HSID'];};

    $HSID = 2;

    $mydb3 = new DB_MySQL('localhost','','','');
    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM hosting_handlungslog WHERE HSID = '$HSID'";
    $mydb3->query($query3);
    while ($row3 = $mydb3->fetchRow()){
        echo json_encode($row3);    
    }
?>
```

The return of the php script looks like this:

```
    {"HLID":"1","HSID":"2","hl_datum":"2014-01-19","hl_info":"n","hl_aenderung":"Windows-UpdatesJava Update"}
    {"HLID":"2","HSID":"2","hl_datum":"2014-02-02","hl_info":"n","hl_aenderung":"Windows-UpdatesTomcat-UpdateApache-Update"}
    {"HLID":"3","HSID":"2","hl_datum":"2014-03-03","hl_info":"n","hl_aenderung":"Windows-UpdatesTomcat-UpdateApache-Update"}
    {"HLID":"4","HSID":"2","hl_datum":"2014-04-13","hl_info":"y","hl_aenderung":"Windows-UpdatesTomcat-Update auf 6.0.39Apache Update 2.4.8 (OpenSSL auf 1.0.1g)"}
    {"HLID":"5","HSID":"2","hl_datum":"2014-04-14","hl_info":"n","hl_aenderung":"Zertifikatsaustausch wegen Heartbleed Bug"}
    {"HLID":"6","HSID":"2","hl_datum":"2014-04-27","hl_info":"y","hl_aenderung":"Java Update auf 7.0.58"}
    {"HLID":"7","HSID":"2","hl_datum":"2014-06-08","hl_info":"y","hl_aenderung":"Windows-UpdatesTomcat-Update auf 6.0.41Apache Update auf 2.4.9 (OpenSSL auf 1.0.1h)Java Update auf 7.0.60"}
    {"HLID":"8","HSID":"2","hl_datum":"2014-07-21","hl_info":"y","hl_aenderung":"Apache Update auf 2.4.10Java Update auf 7.0.62"}
```

What to do here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must save it to another Array and show after gets all data from mysql.

```
<?php
    include_once('../classes/class.mysql.php');

    if (isset($_POST['HSID'])){$HSID = $_POST['HSID'];};

    $HSID = 2;

    $myjsonarray = null;
    $mydb3 = new DB_MySQL('localhost','','','');
    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM hosting_handlungslog WHERE HSID = '$HSID'";
    $mydb3->query($query3);
    while ($row3 = $mydb3->fetchRow()){
        $myjsonarray[] = $row3;    
    }
    echo json_encode($myjsonarray);
?>
```

And now you get this

```
[{"HLID":"1","HSID":"2","hl_datum":"2014-01-19","hl_info":"n","hl_aenderung":"Windows-UpdatesJava Update"},{"HLID":"2","HSID":"2","hl_datum":"2014-02-02","hl_info":"n","hl_aenderung":"Windows-UpdatesTomcat-UpdateApache-Update"},{"HLID":"3","HSID":"2","hl_datum":"2014-03-03","hl_info":"n","hl_aenderung":"Windows-UpdatesTomcat-UpdateApache-Update"},...]
```

Example show in php...

```
<?php 
      echo $myjsonarray[0]["HLID"]; 
      echo $myjsonarray[1]["HLID"]; 
?>
```

In jquery you may use "**for**"

```
for(i=0;i<data.lenght;i++){
    mydata = data[i];
    alert(mydata["HSname"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP to :

```
$tempArray = array();
while ($row3 = $mydb3->fetchRow()){
        tempArray[] = $row3;    
    }
echo json_encode($tempArray);
```

Then in javascript:

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item){
        // Now loop through e.g. 
        $('body').append('<div class="wartungsLogID">' + item.HSID + '</div>');
    });
}
```

Comment: You too, thanks man! Didn't know which one to mark as an answer. Did on natsu cause of his score ;) Hope you're ok with this.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, in the success callback, you need to parse the json (var data).
If you have a table element, you can fill it with your data.
First you need a table and cycle:

```
var t = document.getElementById(mytableId);
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
```

...

inside the loop you need to create a row for every object inside your json:

```
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var td = document.createElement('td');
td.innerHTML = data[i].hl_aenderung;
tr.appendChild(td);
t.appendChild(tr);
```

and repeat this for every field (every object's propery (hl_datum,hl_info,etc.)).

Answer (score 0):

Within the Ajax Success callback you must loop through the array to display each object individually.

Below is an example, including some [best practice](http://gregfranko.com/blog/jquery-best-practices/) techniques:

```
success: function(data) {
    var textToDisplay = '';

    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        textToDisplay += '<li data-id="'+item.HLID+'">'+item.hl_aenderung+'</li>'
    });

    $('ul').append(textToDisplay);
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhvM6/) which you can expand on.